# CCleaner deletes .txt file from temp folder. how do i avoid deletion.(C#)

Tags: file, temp

I have written a .txt file to the **temp folder** for data storage using my program. But when i run junk removing programs such as **CCleaner**. it is important that this file remains in the users system and **I want to know what the best way of stopping it being deleted.**

Do I need to make sure it is in another folder or something? I do not know the method these programs use to determine wheither they should delete a file or not.

Thank You,
Jack

Comment: The whole purpose of `temp` folders is to store data which is easy or not needed to be reconstructed and may hence be discarded. Use another folder!

Comment: you can whitelist folders and/or files in the options of CCleaner